# VSTO Outlook Plugin - If Statement / CurrentUser

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

Is it possible to include an If statement in a VSTO plugin that will offer up different Context Menu items based on the Current User's attributes, e.g. Department?

I am attempting to use the documentation in here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/pia/how-to-get-information-about-the-current-user to add to my existing code:

```html
 <contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuMailItem">
      <menu id="ReplyListContext" label="Choose a Quick Reply" insertBeforeMso="Copy">
        <button id="CharityContext" label="Charity Request" onAction="Charity_Click"/>
>
      </menu>
    </contextMenu>
```

```html
 public void Charity_Click(Office.IRibbonControl control)
        {
            Outlook.Explorer explorer = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer();
            if (explorer != null)
            {
                Outlook.Selection selection = explorer.Selection;
                if (selection.Count >= 1)
                {
                    Outlook.MailItem mailItem = selection[1] as Outlook.MailItem;
                    if (mailItem != null) //could be something other than MailItem

                    {
                        Outlook.MailItem response = mailItem.ReplyAll();

                        response.BodyFormat = Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;

                        response.HTMLBody = "<p>Thanks for your e-mail</p><p>text text text</p><p>Many thanks</p> " + response.HTMLBody;
                        response.Send();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I have a number of these responses and want different departments to be presented with different options when they open Outlook

Answer (score 0):

You could use [DynamicMenu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-customui/26d7db80-7ea4-42d0-9a06-3f63365043c7)

1. In your ribbonXML, add a `dynamicmenu` item:

   ```
   <contextMenus>
           <contextMenu idMso='ContextMenuCell'>
               <dynamicMenu id='dynamicRoot' label='Sample Dynamic' getContent='GetMenuCustomContent' /> 
           </contextMenu>
   </contextMenus>
   ```
2. Your callback function `GetMenuCustomContent` will be called whenever the hosting app (`Outlook`) needs to build the menu.
3. Return different XML according to the CurrentUser.

   ```
   public string GetMenuCustomContent(IRibbonControl control)
   {
       // here get the current user and return different XML
       // accodring to any condition

       if(SomeOtherCondition)
       {
           return @"<menu xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui'>
                       <button id='some_button' label='UserType1' onAction='DoSomething'/>
                   </menu>";
       }
       else if (SomeOtherCondition)
       {
           return @"<menu xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui'>
                       <button id='some_button2' label='UserType2' onAction='DoSomething2'/>
                   </menu>";
       }

       return "";
   }
   ```